# Upgrade to 22.04 does not launch

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

I have been getting the prompt about the upgrade for 22.04 for quite a while now. Looks like this:
[Upgrade Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njjpy.png)

I click upgrade, but then absolutely nothing happens. I've tried it 3-4 times by now.

I have read through this guide https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start, made sure systems fully updated etc - and trawled the www for what's going on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and get back if need be :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it now and get this message: 

"Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading"

I have updated everything, but still get this message.